# Can I publish same Android app with new license key

Tags: android, apk, license-key

Sorry I have a serious problem. I tried to publish an app on play store. I have somehow gotten my license key corrupt. Now the app is ready to publish but it has some issues I need to address. So I decided to sign the app with a new license key. My question is can I unpublish the current app and publish the same app again just with the new key? Thanks in advance for your assistance.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can publish it as a different app, but you have to publish it with a different package name. If you lost your key, you can [request](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/contact/key) Google a new key as well.

Comment: Thank you for your time. It's well appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

If you give google power to sign it on market by google* key storage. If not you must write to support they drop your key. Or just upload app wit new build name.

Comment: Thanks for your swift response. I think I'll right support. I guess that's my best option as my client is waiting on me and I need to prepare for an exam .